# When using less with -S option, it moves text on top when I press right key

Tags: less, more

I am using less as pager in MySQL, and I have configured it with `-S` flag, so that
it does not wrap text.

The only issue is that, when I have a small result set and want to see what is on the right, I press right arrow key and suddenly my text pops up on the first line of terminal.

I known that this isn't a big issue, but it is annoying. I looked in the manual page, but I could not find any option that would help me.

Do you have any suggestion?

Some other pager perhaps, that support `_no wrapping_` and does not suffer from the issue I described here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to report a bug.

I use the `-c` option, so that the text is always at the top. You might be interested in this option as a workaround, in the sense that this makes the bug no longer visible due to the change of the default position of the text.